# Time series analysis and streamflow data

Tags: hydrology

Does anyone know of any examples of (common) time series analysis techniques applied to streamflow data?

Edit:  I am wondering if anyone has come across papers using common time series analysis techniques to identify the peaks in real time streamflow observations.  Additionally, I am wondering if once these peaks have been identified, if any further analysis (such as calculating the time of concentration) have been performed.

Comment: The question is too vague. time series analysis of what? Flood frequency, flood peak, water resources availability, basin response characteristics, climate change trends.....?

Comment: Remove your question here, place it on [OpenData.se], **but only if** you [write a good question](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and if you first [search that it has not been asked there already](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+time+series).